# In Solidity, what is the difference between using if() and require()?

Tags: conditional-statements, blockchain, solidity

I can run code inside a conditional if statement. I can also require a condition before running some code. Are they interchangeable or are there reasons I would choose to rely on one and not the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, they are not interchangeable.

When an `if` condition is false, the next condition/block is executed and the else block (if any) is run. Standard if/else programming logic.

`require` is an error handling statement. When a `require` condition is false, all execution stops and the transaction is rolled back.

See the [Solidity documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html?highlight=require#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions) for error handling for more info on `require` and the differences between that and other error handling functions such as `assert` and `revert`.